# I need to reverse the formatting of an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

I have this object below, and I need to use function `transform(oldScoreKey)` to reformat the object so the letters are the keys and the numbers are the values.

I know how to iterate on every letter within the object using a `for` loop inside of a `for...in` loop, but I don't understand how I'm supposed to have the function do the actual reformatting of the object itself.

Here is my code:

```javascript
//here is the oldScoreKey

const oldScoreKey = {
   1: ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'L', 'N', 'R', 'S', 'T'],
   2: ['D', 'G'],
   3: ['B', 'C', 'M', 'P'],
   4: ['F', 'H', 'V', 'W', 'Y'],
   5: ['K'],
   8: ['J', 'X'],
   10: ['Q', 'Z']
};

//here is the basic format of what I have thus far,
//as far as the layout of the transform function 

function transform(obj) {

  const newScorekey = {};

  for (var key in oldScoreKey) {
    for(let i = 0; i < oldScoreKey[key].length; i++) {
      return oldScoreKey[key][i].toLowerCase();
    }
  } return newScorekey;
}

transform(oldScoreKey);



//the final output should be like this, 
//but it doesn't need to be in this exact order, 
//only such that the point values match those in oldScoreKey

const newScorekey = {
    a: 1,
    b: 3,
    c: 3,
    d: 2,
    e: 1,
    f: 4,
    g: 2,
    h: 4,
    i: 1,
    j: 8,
    k: 5,
    l: 1,
    m: 3,
    n: 1,
    o: 1,
    p: 3,
    q: 10,
    r: 1,
    s: 1,
    t: 1,
    u: 1,
    v: 4,
    w: 4,
    x: 8,
    y: 4,
    z: 10
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't return in the loop, otherwise it'll just return one key and not complete execution, you can populate the `newScoreKey` object instead, and return when the loop is done:

```js
const oldScoreKey = {
   1: ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'L', 'N', 'R', 'S', 'T'],
   2: ['D', 'G'],
   3: ['B', 'C', 'M', 'P'],
   4: ['F', 'H', 'V', 'W', 'Y'],
   5: ['K'],
   8: ['J', 'X'],
   10: ['Q', 'Z']
};

function transform(obj) {
  const newScorekey = {};
  for (var key in oldScoreKey) {
    for (let i = 0; i < oldScoreKey[key].length; i++) {
      newScorekey[oldScoreKey[key][i].toLowerCase()] = +key;
    }
  } return newScorekey;
}

newScorekey = transform(oldScoreKey);

console.log(newScorekey);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying the +key. Everything makes so much more sense now. I wish I had more like 6 more accounts to upvote you more.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate approach using `Object.entries()` and `Array#reduce()`

```js
const oldScoreKey = {
  1: ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'L', 'N', 'R', 'S', 'T'],
  2: ['D', 'G'],
  3: ['B', 'C', 'M', 'P'],
  4: ['F', 'H', 'V', 'W', 'Y'],
  5: ['K'],
  8: ['J', 'X'],
  10: ['Q', 'Z']
};


const transform = (o) =>  Object.entries(o)
    .reduce((acc, [k, arr]) => arr.reduce((a, el) => (a[el.toLowerCase()] = k, a), acc), {});


console.log(transform(oldScoreKey))
```